# Need to send keystrokes into a Citrix window

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, citrix-receiver

Client just got a new system. They're connecting to a program through Citrix. I don't know the exact details but basically the call center connects to a VDI, and then opens the application. The application opens in a Chrome window connecting through Citrix.

Previously, we had created a macro shortcut to switch between programs and populate fields.
Now with Citrix, when we Alt+Tab to the Citrix window, we still cannot tab to the proper field until we've clicked on a field.

Is there any way to send a command to Citrix? I'd like to use some kind of a command to give focus to a specific field.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

- [ControlFocus](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm) or [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) - if the specific field has a
  classname (ClassNN in Window Spy):

  ControlFocus, Control, WinTitle

  ControlClick, Control, WinTitle
- or [ControlClick, Pos](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm), WinTitle  - if the field's relative position to
  the window (shown in Window Spy) is always constant,e.g.:

  ControlClick, x55 y77, WinTitle